# How can I reshape a data.table (long into wide) without doing a function like sum or mean?

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, reshape2, splitstackshape

How can I reshape a `data.table` (long into wide) without doing a function like `sum` or `mean`?
I was looking at dcast/melt/reshape/etc. 
But I don't get the desired results.

This is my data:

```
DT <- data.table(id = c("1","1","2","3"), score = c("5", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Original format:

```
> DT
id score
1  5 
1  4 
2  5 
3  6
```

Desired format:

```
id score1 score2
1  5      4
2  5      NA
3  6      NA
```

I now do the trick with:

```
DT <- DT[, list(list(score)), by=id]
```

But then the contents of the first cell is like:

```
c("5", "4")
```

And I need to split it (I use the package `splitstackshape`):

```
DT <- cSplit(DT, "V1", ",")
```

This is probably not the most efficient method...
What is a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `getanID` to create a unique `.id` for the grouping variable `id`.  Then, try with `dcast.data.table` (or simply `dcast` from versions 1.9.5 and beyond) and if needed change the column names using `setnames`

```
 library(splitstackshape)
 res <- dcast(getanID(DT, 'id'), id~.id,value.var='score')
 setnames(res, 2:3, paste0('score', 1:2))[]
 #    id score1 score2
 #1:  1      5      4
 #2:  2      5     NA
 #3:  3      6     NA
```

Or using only `data.table`

```
 dcast(DT[, .id:=paste0('score', 1:.N), by=id],
       id~.id, value.var='score')
 #   id score1 score2
 #1:  1      5      4
 #2:  2      5     NA
 #3:  3      6     NA
```

Or from the code you were using (less number of characters)

```
cSplit(DT[, toString(score), by=id], 'V1', ',')
#   id V1_1 V1_2
#1:  1    5    4
#2:  2    5   NA
#3:  3    6   NA
```

Comment: Thx a million! I checked which one was the fastest. The cSplit uses less characters, but takes almost double the time needed.

Comment: @peter, What size data are you testing on? On anything of a reasonable size, I would imagine that the `getanID` approach should be reasonably fast (It uses `sequence(.N)` which I'd *guess* would be faster than `paste`). `cSplit` would definitely not be the best choice here though. +1 akrun.

Comment: @Anando, The getanID and the data.table methods are very fast. cSplit is slower. My tables are 300k rows. The data.table method takes 0.74 sec on my machine The cSplit method 2,7 sec.

Comment: @akrun I was searching for this from that time. So i referred this. And thanks for a very nice answer!

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar  Actually, I didn't imply that you got the inspiration from here.  I really forgot that I used it this way.  I was just teasing you about the story behind your thought process :-)

Comment: @akrun I liked this approach very much! and bookmarked it. This is so cool! :)

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar  Thanks for your generous comments.  It made my day!

Comment: Akrun, can you help in this related question, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163500/r-transform-from-wide-to-long-without-sorting-columns/41163691#41163691  the answers provided there don't work as desired.