# Transform from Wide to Long without sorting columns

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, transformation

I want to convert a dataframe from wide format to long format.

Here it is a toy example:

```
mydata <- data.frame(ID=1:5, ZA_1=1:5, 
            ZA_2=5:1,BB_1=rep(3,5),BB_2=rep(6,5),CC_7=6:2)

ID ZA_1 ZA_2 BB_1 BB_2 CC_7
1    1    5    3    6    6
2    2    4    3    6    5
3    3    3    3    6    4
4    4    2    3    6    3
5    5    1    3    6    2
```

There are some variables that will remain as is (here only ID) and some that will be transformed  to long format (here all other variables, all ending with _1, _2 or _7)

In order to transform it to long format I'm using data.table melt and dcast, a generic way able to detect the variables automatically. Other solutions are welcome too.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)
idvars =  grep("_[1-7]$",names(mydata) , invert = TRUE)
temp <- melt(mydata, id.vars = idvars)  
nuevo <- dcast(
  temp[, `:=`(var = sub("_[1-7]$", '', variable),
  measure = sub('.*_', '', variable), variable = NULL)],  
  ... ~ var, value.var='value') 



ID measure BB  CC  ZA
 1      1   3  NA   1
 1      2   6  NA   5
 1      7  NA   6  NA
 2      1   3  NA   2
 2      2   6  NA   4
 2      7  NA   5  NA
 3      1   3  NA   3
 3      2   6  NA   3
 3      7  NA   4  NA
 4      1   3  NA   4
 4      2   6  NA   2
 4      7  NA   3  NA
 5      1   3  NA   5
 5      2   6  NA   1
 5      7  NA   2  NA
```

As you can see the columns are reoredered alphabetically, but I would prefer to keep the original order as far as possible, for example taking into account the order of the first appearance of the variable.

> ID **ZA_1** ZA_2 **BB_1** BB_2 **CC_7**

Should be

```
ID ZA BB CC
```

I don't mind if the idvars columns come alltogether at the beginning or if they also stay in their original position.

> ID **ZA_1** ZA_2 TEMP **BB_1** BB_2 CC_2 CC_1

would be

```
ID ZA TEMP BB CC
```

or

```
ID TEMP ZA BB CC
```

I prefer the last option.

Another problem is that everything gets transformed to character.

Comment: As far as I've seen they are simple solutions when you specify variable names manually.  But I need an automated way to do it, with grep, because my whole dataset has 3500 variables.

Comment: @Jaap the question is not the same because I focus on two problems: I don't want the output to be reordered, and I need a memory efficient solution, not just the trivial solution as the the other question you link, and my pattern is more complex.  Uwe's solution is the good solution, and it was already accepted one year ago.  Nobody at your link provides a good solution, so please remove your "duplicate question" tag from this question because it's not a duplicated.

Comment: Thx for the explanation. I've reopend the question & also posted an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP has updated his answer to his own question complaining about the memory consumption of the intermediate `melt()` step when half of the columns are `id.vars`. He requested that *`data.table` needs a direct way to do it without creating giant middle steps*.

Well, `data.table` already does have that ability, it's called *join*.

Given the sample data from the Q, the whole operation can be implemented in a less memory consuming way by reshaping with only one id.var and later joining the reshaped result with the original data.table:

```
setDT(mydata)

# add unique row number to join on later 
# (leave `ID` col as placeholder for all other id.vars)
mydata[, rn := seq_len(.N)]

# define columns to be reshaped
measure_cols <- stringr::str_subset(names(mydata), "_\\d$")

# melt with only one id.vars column
molten <- melt(mydata, id.vars = "rn", measure.vars = measure_cols)

# split column names of measure.vars
# Note that "variable" is reused to save memory 
molten[, c("variable", "measure") := tstrsplit(variable, "_")]

# coerce names to factors in the same order as the columns appeared in mydata
molten[, variable := forcats::fct_inorder(variable)]

# remove columns no longer needed in mydata _before_ joining to save memory
mydata[, (measure_cols) := NULL]

# final dcast and right join
result <- mydata[dcast(molten, ... ~ variable), on = "rn"]
result
#    ID rn measure ZA BB CC
# 1:  1  1       1  1  3 NA
# 2:  1  1       2  5  6 NA
# 3:  1  1       7 NA NA  6
# 4:  2  2       1  2  3 NA
# 5:  2  2       2  4  6 NA
# 6:  2  2       7 NA NA  5
# 7:  3  3       1  3  3 NA
# 8:  3  3       2  3  6 NA
# 9:  3  3       7 NA NA  4
#10:  4  4       1  4  3 NA
#11:  4  4       2  2  6 NA
#12:  4  4       7 NA NA  3
#13:  5  5       1  5  3 NA
#14:  5  5       2  1  6 NA
#15:  5  5       7 NA NA  2
```

Finally, you may remove the row number if no longer needed by `result[, rn := NULL]`.

Furthermore, you can remove the intermediate `molten` by `rm(molten)`.

We have started with a `data.table` consisting of 1 id column, 5 measure cols and 5 rows. The reshaped result has 1 id column, 3 measure cols, and 15 rows. So, the data volume stored in id columns effectively has tripled. However, the intermediate step needed only one id.var `rn`.

**EDIT** If *memory consumption is crucial*, it might be worthwhile to consider to keep the id.vars and the measure.vars in two separate data.tables and to join only the necessary id.var columns with the measure.vars on demand.

Note that the `measure.vars` parameter to `melt()`allows for a special function `patterns()`. With this the call to `melt()` could have been written as well as

```
molten <- melt(mydata, id.vars = "rn", measure.vars = patterns("_\\d$"))
```

Comment: I'll try it. In order not to use extra packages can I use  grep("_\\d$",names(mydata2), value = T )  and  molten[,var:=factor(variable, levels=unique(variable))]  instead?   I've also tried patterns() before but I had some problems with it.

Comment: Yes, of course you can, should work as well. However, I recommend to use these to two packages which have been initiated by Hadley Wickham in his efforts to improve usabilty of R.

Comment: Please, watch out, it should read `molten[, variable := factor(variable, levels = unique(variable))]` instead of `molten[,var:=factor(variable, levels=unique(variable))]` in order to save memory.

Comment: I think the  "remove columns no longer needed ..." should be located after the cast, or maybe remove them as rows instead, isn't it?

Comment: No, these are the old measure cols `ZA_1`, `ZA_2`, etc, in `mydata` whose contents are now part of `molten`. You may skip this statement and keep those columns in `mydata` for quality assurance but they are essentially redundant and only will contribute to the memory footprint of `result`. This is why I suggest to remove them _before_ the join (`dcast()`only uses `molten`. I've put join and `dcast()` in one statement avoiding to create another temporary variable). To scrutinize the code you may intersperse calls to `str(molten)`.

Comment: Note that the old measure cols are removed from `mydata` not from `molten`.

Comment: It works very well.  Though I've tried a much larger dataset and found that R fills a lot of memory and it doesn't recover most of it even using gc(). I have to first break the data in chunks.  I think R it's not the proper tool to deal with big data.

Comment: "big" data is relative. By default, R is working in memory. So, you need a sufficiently sized hardware, anyway. However, the section on _Large memory and out-of-memory data_ in the [CRAN HPC task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) lists 11 packages which help to deal with this kind of situations.

Comment: Today I've tried again and  mydata[, rn := seq_len(.N)]   produces this warning  Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(my, , `:=`(rn, seq_len(.N))) :
  Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a (shallow) copy of the data.table so that := can add this new column by reference. At an earlier point, this data.table has been copied by R (or been created manually using structure() or similar).

Comment: @skan It's only a warning about a potential inefficiency. `data.table` over-allocates the column list vector to have space for adding additional columns efficiently, see `?truelength`. Somewhere in the previous processing steps an operation (some are mentioned in the warning) have caused the over-allocation got lost.

Comment: Another thing:  My dataset is very large and I introduced your code in a loop appending the result in a file.  Later when I try to read the file I get this warning "Warning: stack imbalance in '<-', 2 then 1" . What does it mean?

Comment: @skan Haven't seen that error message before. I think it's better to post a new question including a [mcve]. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can melt several columns simultaneously, if you pass a list of column names to the argument `measure =`. One approach to do this in a scalable manner would be to:

1. Extract the column names and the corresponding first two letters:

   ```
   measurevars <- names(mydata)[grepl("_[1-9]$",names(mydata))]
   groups <- gsub("_[1-9]$","",measurevars)
   ```
2. Turn `groups` into a factor object and make sure levels aren't ordered alphabetically. We'll use this in the next step to create a list object with the correct structure.

   ```
   split_on <- factor(groups, levels = unique(groups))
   ```
3. Create a list using `measurevars` with `split()`, and create vector for the `value.name =` argument in `melt()`.

   ```
   measure_list <- split(measurevars, split_on)
   measurenames <- unique(groups)
   ```

Bringing it all together:

```
melt(setDT(mydata), 
     measure = measure_list, 
     value.name = measurenames,
     variable.name = "measure")
#    ID measure ZA BB
# 1:  1       1  1  3
# 2:  2       1  2  3
# 3:  3       1  3  3
# 4:  4       1  4  3
# 5:  5       1  5  3
# 6:  1       2  5  6
# 7:  2       2  4  6
# 8:  3       2  3  6
# 9:  4       2  2  6
#10:  5       2  1  6
```

Comment: My whole dataset has 3500 variables. This is just a toy example. That's why I'm using the more complex way to find automatically the variables to melt and cast, with grep.

Comment: put it simple, they all end with _x   where x is a single digit.

Comment: And how do you avoid that everything is casted to characters?

Comment: I've tried your code and   measurenames <- as.character(unique(levels))  produces an error: Error in unique.default(levels) : "unique() applies only to vectors".  I guess you need to add split_on inside levels()

Comment: For future use I will compare your method (only needs a melt) with mine (needs melt and dcast) and benchmark both in speed and memory usage.

Comment: And I think is better to use  gsub("_[1-9]$","",measurevars) 
 instead of groups <- gsub("[^A-Z]","", measurevars).  It won't modify any number or symbol inside the main name

Comment: If I try with **mydata <- data.frame(ID=1:5, ZA_2001=1:5,  ZA_2002=5:1,BB_2001=rep(3,5),BB_2002=rep(6,5), CC_2007=rep(6,5))** and using **"_20[0-9][0-9]$"** the measure column is populated with 1 and 2 instead of 2001, 2002 and 2007, why?

Comment: or just mydata <- data.frame(ID=1:5, ZA_1=1:5, ZA_2=5:1,BB_1=rep(3,5),BB_2=rep(6,5), CC_7=rep(6,5)). The CC_7 values are missplaced.  I think your method expects all the variable names to have the same number of variations. And it doesn't use the _xxxx information, only the position in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using base R functions `split.default` and `do.call`.

```
# split the non-ID variables into groups based on their name suffix
myList <- split.default(mydata[-1], gsub(".*_(\\d)$", "\\1", names(mydata[-1])))

# append variables by row after setting the regularizing variable names, cbind ID
cbind(mydata[1],
      do.call(rbind, lapply(myList, function(x) setNames(x, gsub("_\\d$", "", names(x))))))
    ID ZA BB
1.1  1  1  3
1.2  2  2  3
1.3  3  3  3
1.4  4  4  3
1.5  5  5  3
2.1  1  5  6
2.2  2  4  6
2.3  3  3  6
2.4  4  2  6
2.5  5  1  6
```

The first line splits the data.frame variables (minus ID) into lists that agree on the final character of their variable name. This criterion is determined using `gsub`. The second line uses `do.call` to call `rbind` on this list of variables, modified with `setNames` so that the final digit and underscore are removed from their names. Finally, `cbind` attaches the ID to the resulting data.frame.

Note that the data has to be structured regularly, with no missing variables, etc.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach with `data.table`:

```
melt(mydata, id = 'ID')[, c("variable", "measure") := tstrsplit(variable, '_')
                        ][, variable := factor(variable, levels = unique(variable))
                          ][, dcast(.SD, ID + measure ~ variable, value.var = 'value')]
```

which gives:

> ```
>     ID measure ZA BB CC
>  1:  1       1  1  3 NA
>  2:  1       2  5  6 NA
>  3:  1       7 NA NA  6
>  4:  2       1  2  3 NA
>  5:  2       2  4  6 NA
>  6:  2       7 NA NA  5
>  7:  3       1  3  3 NA
>  8:  3       2  3  6 NA
>  9:  3       7 NA NA  4
> 10:  4       1  4  3 NA
> 11:  4       2  2  6 NA
> 12:  4       7 NA NA  3
> 13:  5       1  5  3 NA
> 14:  5       2  1  6 NA
> 15:  5       7 NA NA  2
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found the way, modifying my initial solution

```
mydata <- data.table(ID=1:5, ZA_2001=1:5, ZA_2002=5:1,
BB_2001=rep(3,5),BB_2002=rep(6,5),CC_2007=6:2)

idvars =  grep("_20[0-9][0-9]$",names(mydata) , invert = TRUE)
temp <- melt(mydata, id.vars = idvars)  
temp[, `:=`(var = sub("_20[0-9][0-9]$", '', variable), 
measure = sub('.*_', '', variable), variable = NULL)]  
temp[,var:=factor(var, levels=unique(var))]
dcast( temp,   ... ~ var, value.var='value' )
```

And it gives you the proper measure values.
Anyway this solution needs a lot of memory.

The trick was converting the var variable to factor specifying the order I want with levels, as mtoto did.
mtoto solution is nice because it doesn't need to cast and melt, only melt, but doesn't work in my updated example, only works when there are the same number of number variations for each word.

PD:
I've being parsing every step and found that the melt step could be a big problem when working with large datatables. If you have a data.table with just 100000 rows x 1000 columns and use half of the columns as id.vars the output is approx 50000000 x 500, just too much to continue with the next step.
data.table needs a direct way to do it without creating giant middle steps.